# Given the Joint PDF find the value of $c$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Given the following Joint PDF

\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) =  \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            c & \quad -1< x \leq 1 ;  \lvert x \rvert <y \\
            0 & otherwise
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

$1.$ Find the value of $c$.

My attempt:

Since Given function is PDF, then by the the property of PDF we have:

$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-y}^{y}c*dxdy=1$

$c\int_{-1}^1(2y)dy=1$

$c(1^2-(-1)^2)=1$

$c*0 = 1$

$0=1$

Where am I making the mistake?
Please guide me. Why value of $c$ is not being found?

Comment: What is the actual support?  You are integrating over  $-1<y<1, -y < x < y$ (half of which is a negative area).  Also $-1<x<1, \lvert x\rvert <y$ is invalid for a uniform distribution..

Comment: The question contains an error, because the region for which $-1 < x \le 1$ and $|x| < y$ has infinite area.

Answer (score 1):

Probabily the region is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:-1<x<1;|x|<y<1\}$

It is understood that this assumption is only one of the infinity possibilities...I assumed this only to explain to the OP how the exercise could work...

Assuming this, $f_X(x)=c$ is uniform over the $(x,y)$ support that is a triangle with area 1 thus it is self evident that $c=1$. If the correct exercise is different, the procedure is the same....do a drawing of the support area, calculate it and consider as $f(x)$ its reciprocal

[image]